# How to use a legacy C# library class object in a MAUI model

Tags: c#, .net, maui

We have some classes defined in a legacy C# library and we need to use them as a model for a View in a MAUI app.

We have looked at many sources, but many suggest creating a MAUI library, which is not possible for us, because it is an already well-defined and tested object library.

That library is used not only by Apps on various platforms, but also C# applications on Linux, Windows and MacOS.

We already added it to the `Dependencies`,

Do we have to convert it into a NuGet package?

How and where should we place some indications (in view `cs` and/or `XAML` file?, in app `cs` and/or `XAML` file?, other?) to bind an object from that C# library in the view?

Thanks in advance, it’s probably not that difficult, but we’re starting to use MAUI and we’re a little stuck here.

---

The object library component has just been upgraded to **.NET 6.0** (it is the last LTS available), so it is no longer a legacy library.

```xml
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
<LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

But the question of how to bind an object from that C# library in the view, still.

Comment: Please provide more information about the library and explain what you've tried to do already. Which target frameworks does your library support?

Comment: "legacy" is pretty vague.  .NET has been around 20+ years, there are a LOT of varieties of "library" out there

Comment: Maui is simply a cross-platform UI, that runs on top of modern .Net. It has no relevance to your situation, other than **requiring an up-to-date .Net version**. Make a new project from [.Net class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio?pivots=dotnet-7-0) template. Target .Net 6 or newer. Move your library sources to it. Build. Fix any incompatibilities, if necessary. Reference that from your Maui project.

Comment: Thanks ewerspej, @Jason and ToolmakerSteve, we follow your suggestions at least for the models, but they are still in an external project and assembly for multiple integration reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a class library (.dll) which targets a .NET version less or equal to the version of your MAUI project, you can simply add it as a COM reference and then use the data types that are defined inside the library by following three simple steps.

For this example, I've used a simple class library called "SampleClassLibrary.dll" which only contains a single class called `SampleModel` inside the `SampleClassLibrary` namespace:

```cs
namespace SampleClassLibrary
{
    public class SampleModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

## 1. Add Library to Solution

First, you should decide where the library should exist. Ideally, this is a location where you would also add other external libraries which are not added via NuGet. I usually create a separate folder for these dependencies and then I add the library into that folder in the solution:

[image: Add Library to Solution]

Depending on the linker settings and other factors, you may want to copy the library to the output directory, but this shouldn't be strictly necessary:

[image: Copy Library to Output Folder]

## 2. Add Library as COM Reference

Next, you need to right click "Dependencies" on the project and select "Add COM Reference". In the following dialog, browse to the location of the library and select it with the checkmark:

[image: Add COM Dependency]

Once you've selected the library, hit "OK" and you are good to go.

## 3. Use Types from Library

Now, you can use the `SampleModel` class in the MAUI project as a model, e.g. in a ViewModel by adding a `using` statement that pulls in the namespace from the library.

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using SampleClassLibrary;

namespace MauiWithDll;

public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    // SampleModel is defined in the SampleClassLibrary
    private SampleModel _sampleModel;
    public SampleModel SampleModel
    {
        get => _sampleModel;
        set => SetProperty(ref _sampleModel, value);
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SampleModel = new SampleModel
        {
            Name = "Jack Sparrow",
            Description = "Pirate"
        };
    }
}
```

Now, you can [bind to the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm) and implement your MAUI app with it:

**View code-behind:**

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

**View XAML:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:mauiWithDll="clr-namespace:MauiWithDll"
  x:DataType="mauiWithDll:MainViewModel"
  x:Class="MauiWithDll.MainPage">

  <VerticalStackLayout
    Spacing="25"
    Padding="30,0"
    VerticalOptions="Center">

    <Label Text="{Binding SampleModel.Name}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding SampleModel.Description}" />

  </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Note that any bindings to objects of external library classes will only update automatically in a MAUI project, if the model class implements the *[INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged)* interface.