# .NET 7.0 Project Reference: "Could not load file or assembly" when loading external Class Library DLL during runtime

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-assembly, .net-7.0

I am creating a Class Library DLL (.NET 7.0), and I'm trying to test referencing the DLL from a Console App (.NET 7.0). Visual Studio detects all of the references in the code and there are no build errors at all. When I run the Console Application, as soon as it tries to call the reference DLL, it throws an exception:

```
5/9/2023 12:12:33 PM|Error|WebSocket.messages|System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ExampleSharp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
                       File name: 'ExampleSharp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
                          at ExampleSharpDemo.Connection.OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
                          at WebSocketSharp.Server.WebSocketBehavior.onMessage(Object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
                          at WebSocketSharp.Ext.Emit[TEventArgs](EventHandler`1 eventHandler, Object sender, TEventArgs e)
                          at WebSocketSharp.WebSocket.messages(MessageEventArgs e)
```

Here is my .csproj for ExampleSharpDemo:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NETCore.Encrypt" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="WebSocketSharp-netstandard" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="ExampleWebSockets">
      <HintPath>..\..\ExampleWebSockets\ExampleWebSockets\bin\Release\net7.0\publish\win-x86\ExampleWebSockets.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ExampleSharp">
      <HintPath>..\ExampleSharp\bin\Release\net7.0\publish\win-x86\ExampleSharp.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here is my .csproj for ExampleSharp:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NETCore.Encrypt" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="ExampleWebSockets">
      <HintPath>..\..\ExampleWebSockets\ExampleWebSockets\bin\Release\net7.0\publish\win-x86\ExampleWebSockets.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

I've already tried rebuilding, running it as x86, deleting the reference and adding it again. I've also loaded in the "ExampleWebSockets" and "NETCore.Encrypt" dependencies for "ExampleSharp". I have no idea why it fails to load the assembly. I opened it in multiple dependency walkers and they all seem to detect it fine.

EDIT:
I've also tried using Procmon to see why the dependency could not be loaded, but it seems like it finds the file is found with the result "FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS"? I'm pretty confused.

Additional Info:
I plan to distribute this Class Library as an external DLL. The end users (developers) will not have access to the source for "ExampleSharp". So, I can't just include the project reference directly. Though, I will mention when I include the project reference directly, it works fine and I do not get this exception.

Is there something I'm missing? Is .NET 7.0 just not meant to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Does this happen in Debug and Release modes? There are some suspicious `HintPath` items that point to a specific folder and configuration. What are your linker settings and how did you add the dependency to that library?

Comment: @ewerspej Thanks for the response. This happens in Debug, Release and when I publish. What do you mean by "suspicious" hint paths? I added the dependency by right-clicking on the project and clicking "Add Project Reference" and then I browsed for the DLLs. I did it this way because the developers I plan to distribute the "ExampleSharp" DLL to will not have access to the source for "ExampleSharp".

Comment: Why are you referencing the DLL and not include its project in this solution?

Comment: @t3chb0t Apparently, the project will not be accessible to consumers and thus needs to be treated as an external dependency.

Comment: @ewerspej That's right, and I appreciate the suggestion because when I include the project directly from the source, I don't get this exception.

Comment: @ewerspej this is a pretty weird setup. Nobody does that. It'd be even more resonable to create a nuget package for it, even if manually.

Comment: If you own both projects then including it is the primary way to go. If you don't want to do this then you should export the library as a nuget package as this can also be handled automatically much better than a direct DLL.

Comment: @t3chb0t A NuGet is one way to do it, but so are COM references. There can be different reasons for it and I'm not to judge about the motivation of this. Anyway, the DLL should be included in the project and either needs to be linked into the output assembly of the consuming project or it needs to be copied to the output directory of it.

Comment: @t3chb0t I understand, but can I distribute a nuget package without publishing it? Do I have to create a server for that? Sorry, I've never distributed a class library before.

Comment: a nuget package is just a zip with a differnt extension. You can install it from anywhere. I publish them into some folder and install them from there. You don't need a server. Once you get how it works you'll love it ;]

Comment: I will look into using nuget instead then. Thank you both for the recommendations.

Comment: Indeed, that is possible. You can still also do it by referencing the DLL, similar to this where the OP was dealing with a legacy library: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76152827/4308455. I do agree with the NuGet approach in general.

Comment: @ewerspej sure one can do this, we all done this before nuget was there, but then you have to keep a copy of the dll, version it somehow, update it manually, change the path. Lot's of headaches. I wouldn't do this unless it's the last last last resort solution.

Comment: @t3chb0t It depends on how often the DLL changes. With the NuGet you're just simplifying the process, especially without a server you'll always have to keep a dedicated folder around.

Comment: @t3chb0t One question, is it possible to obfuscate the DLL before packing it into the nupkg?

Comment: I'm not sure how good they are. There are tools that can wrap a dll into an ecrypted dll so that you need a dongle or some license to execute it. We used to use one couple of years ago, but don't know what's currently the state of the art. You'll have to google or ask another question.

Comment: @t3chb0t I have a tool, but where I'm lost is how to get "dotnet pack" to pick up the Obfuscated DLL rather than the plain DLL. Part of what led me here in the first place hehe

Comment: are you obfuscating it because you don't want to reveal its source code or are embedding there some other secretes like keys etc? If this tool doesn't support much automation would do this: create a nuget package as usual, encrypt the dll and replace the dll inside the package with an encrypted/obfuscated one most likely with powershell. I'm lazy ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t Yeah, from my research, some kind of automation will be needed. Thanks!

Comment: or you can write for that purpose another console-app and execute it automatically at the end of the build with a build task. It would mean to add a couple of new xml elements to your csproj-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from @t3chb0t and @ewerspej, I learned that this is a pretty archaic and inefficient way of distributing a DLL these days.

Instead, it made a lot more sense to create a NuGet package (which is essentially just a ZIP file) and distribute that to the end user (developer in this instance). NuGet seems to help with the headache of directly referencing the DLLs.

To obfuscate my DLL in the nupkg, I had to use my obfuscation tool and then replace the DLL in place before calling the `dotnet pack` command.